# Cocoa get disk in NSArray

Tags: cocoa, iokit, diskarbitration

hi I'm using DiskArbitration.framework to get list of disks

```
+(NSArray*)arrayOfDisks {
    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    if (session) {
        DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, NULL, driveGo, NULL);
        DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session,
                                     CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
        CFRelease(session);
    }
    return nil;
}

void driveGo(DADiskRef disk, void *context) {
    NSLog(@"%s", DADiskGetBSDName(disk));
}
```

it logs up just fine, but how can I return array back?
it just loop so I even dont know how to check is it done or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your method and store the array in a private variable:

```
(void*) driveGo(DADiskRef disk, void *context) {
NSLog(@"%s", DADiskGetBSDName(disk));
self->_myArray = DADiskGetBSDName(disk);
```

}

Comment: I cant return disk coz it does not exist in arrayOfDisks method, and void driveGo looks like calls couple times so it can not be returned also

Comment: DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback should use void  :(
I am trying to get NSArray of all disks in to my cocoa app

Answer (score 0):

> it just loop so I even dont know how to check is it done or not.

There is no “done”. Your callback will be called for every “disk” that is currently known to DiskArb *and* every “disk” that appears from then on. There is no separation between the two.

Most applications should work with that, rather than against it. Let DiskArb tell you the moment new “disks” appear, change (DescriptionChanged), are mounted or unmounted (also DescriptionChanged), or disappear. Keep your information up to date as those changes come in, and always have the current state.

Most applications do not need to get a complete and fixed snapshot of the current set of mounted volumes. But if, for some reason, you do, you might try the `getmntinfo` function instead.